# Custom application directory in PHP-FPM container

Tags: php, docker

I'm using the `php:7-fpm` Docker image but I cannot put my application in `/var/www/html`. Instead, I want to put it in `/opt/foo`. `/opt/foo` is a volume. How can I do this without replacing the whole PHP-FPM configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP-FPM defaults to the working directory, but because the image sets the working directory before it sets the command, you can't customize it with `WORKDIR`. So the only way to do it neatly seems to be appending to the PHP-FPM configuration file:

```
RUN echo 'chdir = /opt/foo' >> /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```